# fetch data from multiple tables using LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join

i have 3 tables, A, B and C. The relations are as follows:

A OTO B and B OTM C.

I wanted to filter the results by some column in C table by using B + "." (B.Blob.IsDeleted == 0) but i get the below error message

> "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties"

Is it possible to use this approach or that i have to use "Join" key ward to perform a query from multiple tables?

Thanks.

Comment: That's the wrong question. EF deals withe *entities* not tables. If the three entities are related, the relation should be defined in their mapping. This way loading the root entity will load *all* related entities. If you have to look for joins, it's a sign that you are missing relationships

Comment: Sorry, i meant entity, as entity represents a table. I heave 3 entities (as i mentioned above), i just want to fetch data from all the three entities with a different filters from all the three entities.

Comment: I need something like select * from A a, B b, C c where a.id = b.Emp_id and b.id = c.Role_Id. using Entity Framework and LINQ

Comment: Entities mean relationships. You are still talking about tables. Entity A should have Employer and Role properties. Loading A would lazily load both the  corresponding Employer and Role objects. You'd only have to write `context.As.Where(a=>a.Id==someValue)`. If wanted to load all of them with a single round-trip you could write `context.As.Include(a=>a.Employee).Include(a=>a.Role).Where(a=>a.Id==someValue)`

Comment: PS entities *don't* represent tables. They are *independent* classes that get mapped to tables that may or may not look the same. One entity may map to more than one table. One table may map to more than one entities.

Answer (score 0):

The `Include` function only tells EF to *pre-fetch* the `Include`d entities, this is not the same as executing a query that joins together data from multiple related tables.

So the following code:

```
myContext.TableA.Include("B").First();
```

This tells entity framework to also load the entity which is pointed to by the navigation property "B".  This is not quite the same thing as doing a `Join()` query, although it can have a very similar fact.

If your requirement is to fetch entity `A` with some criteria, and then all of the entities that are related to A via the navigation properties from A->B, and B->C, then this should work for you.

If you want to do something more complex such as joining on different properties (fields), querying for A based on a property of B or C; then the `Include` function is not going to work for you.

Comment: I just want to fetch data according to some filter of all the three entities' fields. if i would use SQL query, it was something like... 
select * from A a, B b, C c where a.id = b.Emp_id and b.id = c.Role_Id. the results here were after i filtered by all the three tables. now i want the same by using Entity Framework and LINQ